# H Captcha on a web page without submit button or callback

Tags: python, selenium, callback, captcha, hcaptcha

I use Python and the selenium libary. My problem is that on the internet page top.gg when you vote there is a H captcha that opens automaitically. The problem is I can't find a callback function. I use 2captcha to get the token. Does anyone have a clue how to solve such a H captcha. Or is there a hidden callback function. There is at least no submit button and if you press outside the captcha the captcha is closed and the vote process is terminated. And you have to vote again.

I already tried it with the add on from anycaptcha callback hooker [Callback hooker](https://docs.anycaptcha.com/extensions/bypass-hcaptcha-funcaptcha-callback-with-extension). This uses this script in the console (`document.getElementById('anycaptchaSolveButton').onclick('TOKEN_FROM_STEP_4');`)
Problem is with me this always gives an error (

```
Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...).onclick is not a function)
```

Answer (score 0):

When calling this command, you are inside the iframe where is the anycaptcha button?
See the location of the button anycaptcha. If it is inside an iframe, then you need to first make a switch into it